# The value for an unsigned byte was too large or too small

Tags: c#, memory, byte

I'm trying to write some byte to a game.

Function source code:

```
public void updateStatistic(string prestigeValue, string experience, string winrate, string loserate)
{
    VAMemory vam = new VAMemory(process);
    vam.WriteByte((IntPtr)0x145D114B9, byte.Parse(prestigeValue));
    vam.WriteByte((IntPtr)0x145D114B5, byte.Parse(experience));
    vam.WriteByte((IntPtr)0x145D10E05, byte.Parse(winrate));
    vam.WriteByte((IntPtr)0x145D12240, byte.Parse(loserate));
}
```

Sadly I'm receiving the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The value for an unsigned byte was too large or too small.
```

The type of the address is 4 Bytes. And the values I'm trying to post are: prestigeValue = 1, experience = 1500000, winrate = 100, loserate= 50

Does anyone have a idea how I could get this working?

Comment: The exception is coming from [`byte.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0s9b1y3(v=vs.110).aspx), so one (or more) of `prestigeValue`, `experience`, `winrate`, or `loserate` has a value less than 0 or greater than 255 as indicated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte(v=vs.110).aspx). You may have a misunderstanding of what values are actually stored in each byte position.

Comment: Values are the following: prestigeValue = 1, experience = 1500000, winrate = 100, loserate= 50

Comment: A byte cannot hold a value of 150,000. What makes you think the `experience` value is read from that 1 byte memory location? If you are correct that the value is really held in that byte, then my first guess is that they take that value and multiply it by 10,000 before displaying it, e.g., maybe the value is actually 150 as a byte but in display it shows 150,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first lets start from the beginning.

The VAMemory is a DLL obtained from probably this reference. 
http://www.vivid-abstractions.net/logical/programming/vamemory-c-memory-class-net-3-5/

It allows you to write to a particular memory location. Very useful for doing certain things.

Since the value you are trying to write is a 32bit value. Why don't you use

```
vam.WriteInt32((IntPtr)0x145D114B5, byte.Parse(experience));
```

instead?

Or alternatively, you could probably break your bytes up into single bytes like

```
var experience_int = int.parse(experience);
vam.WriteByte((IntPtr)0x145D114B5, (byte)experience_int & 0xFF);
vam.WriteByte((IntPtr)0x145D114B6, (byte)(experience_int>>8) & 0xFF);
vam.WriteByte((IntPtr)0x145D114B7, (byte)(experience_int>>16 & 0xFF);
vam.WriteByte((IntPtr)0x145D114B8, (byte)(experience_int>>24) & 0xFF);
```

Note that I did not test the code, nor did I check the ordering but it should be something like this.

For more information:
The reason why you get the exception mentioned is because when you call Byte.Parse() but the string that you put in is greater than 255. As you can see mscorlib.dll is the place that is throwing the exception. Inside the MSCoreLib, the exception is throw like this.

```
if (num < 0 || num > (int) byte.MaxValue) 
    throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Byte"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use int.Parse(value)

1500000 is too big of a number to store in a byte.

EDIT: You also need to find a method that writes an int to memory.